# How to get local computer name after New-PSSession -Computername?

Tags: powershell

I am getting the below error, please advise how to fix this error for null-valued expression

```
You cannnot call a method on a null-valued expression 
+CategoryInfo : InvalidOoperation: (:)[], RuntimeException
+FullyQualifiedErrorId: InvokeMethodonNull
+PSComputerName: DC1
```

Code below

```
function myfunction (){
$remoteserver = 'DC1'
$Session = New-PSSession -Computername $remoteserver -Credential $Cred
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$local= $env:COMPUTERNAME

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $remoteserver -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock 
{$using:local 
if($local.substring(5,3) -imatch "Sys") {
Get-ADComputer $local | Move-ADObject -Targetpath "ou=PRD,ou=Servers,dc=com,dc=Companycorp,dc=net"} 
} 
} #end function 
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $remoteserver -ScriptBlock ${Function:myFunction}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is the `$using:` scope.  If you define variables that you want to use in your remote execution, you need to access them like:

```
$PC = $env:ComputerName
Invoke-Command -Computer DC01 -ScriptBlock { $using:PC <# logic #> }
```

If you mean you want to remote into `DC01` to run commands against `localhost`, you're going to run into the second-hop problem due to Kerberos.

---

Update: Your new example looks pretty convoluted.  Here's an example that should work:

```
$MyPC = $env:ComputerName
$Session = New-PSSession -Credential (Get-Credential) -ComputerName 'DC1'

Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock {
    Import-Module -Name 'ActiveDirectory'

    $PC = $using:MyPC
    If ($PC.Substring(5,3) -eq 'sys')
    {
        Get-ADComputer -Identity $PC |
            Move-ADObject -TargetPath 'ou=PRD,ou=Servers,dc=com,dc=Companycorp,dc=net'
    }
}
```

Comment: how do I incorporate a function to the scriptblock?

Comment: @HenryB Add a `$ComputerName` or similar parameter to your function and pass it in the `-ArgumentList` parameter on `Invoke-Command`

Comment: Thanks. I am using your original code, however, I am getting an error that you cannot call a method on a null-valued expression. + PSComputerName: DC01

Comment: @HenryB You already defined a new session on the remote computer with `$session = New-PSSession -Computername DC01 -Credential $cred`, use `Invoke-Command -Session $session` instead of `Invoke-Command -ComputerName DC01`

Comment: @HenryB That means you're trying to do something with a `$Null` variable because it never got assigned.

Comment: @Manu Might help to @ mention him otherwise he won't see a notification.

Comment: @HenryB, are you sure `DC01` exists? Are you trying to use an example with a machine that does not exist in your environment?

Comment: yes it exists. I put all my code in the Scriptblock {$using: PC code here } before this line is the $session-new-pssession -Computername DC01 -Credential $cred

Comment: if I write $computername it shows the local pc not the DC

Comment: I fixed it! I wrote if $computername -ne $NULL { before the invoke-command

Comment: @HenryB A minor improvement: When comparing to `$Null`, always put it first in the comparison so a collection doesn't accidentally return `$True` or worse, nothing at all.  In this case, `$Null -ne $ComputerName`

Comment: sorry to bump this thread but I am still getting null-valued expression errors. I will update the first post with the code shortly

Comment: you did not get the "You cannnot call a method on a null-valued expression " error on DC1?

Comment: Yes I am getting the error on the last line Invoke-Command -ComputerName $remoteserver -ScriptBlock ${Function:myFunction}

Comment: @HenryB Why are you using `-ComputerName $remoteserver -ScriptBlock ${Function:myFunction}` still if you took the answer from my update?

Comment: I followed your advice and code, removed the function and put everything under the scriptblock. getting the same error on DC1 (you cannot call a method on a null-valued expression)

Comment: For some reason, it looks like your `$PC` value is `$Null`

Comment: yes $PC = $env:ComputerName is at the top. When I write-host $PC I do get the local computer name

Comment: TheIncorrigible1, any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: @HenryB What's your powershell version? `$using:` isn't supported until v3.

Comment: I have powershell version 5.0. I simplified my code and will post a new thread about it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47437911/cannot-move-computer-to-target-ou-powershell-script

Comment: I suspect $using: variable isnt working..because when I print $PC it comes back to DC1

Comment: Update, this fixed it after checking for null values for computername and using the code $PC = $using:MyPC

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `Invoke-Command` :

```
$session = New-PSSession -Computername DC01 -Credential $cred

Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {
    $remoteComputerName = $env:computername
}
```

Comment: Your example doesn't make sense.  You can define the script block as the function definition and pass parameters that way.

Comment: I have deleted 5 minutes before you made the comment as I made a mistake in the code ;-)

Answer (score 0):

What I think you're asking is 'how do I open a session on a remote pc, but then still run commands on my local PC'.  If that's so, then let's walk through it.

First, we can open a remote connection to another computer in PowerShell by creating a new PSSession, as you're doing here:

```
$session = New-PSSession -Computername DC01 -Credential $cred
```

You can then either step into the remote computer wholly using `Enter-PSSession`, or just send individual commands to the remote computer using:

```
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {#Commands to run on the remote PC}`
 -Session $session
```

Once you enter the remote PC, you can return to your own PC using the `Exit-PSSession` command.

```
#Enter Remote PC
Enter-PSSession $session

DC01> hostname

*DC01*

#Step out of Remote PC
Exit-PSSession

PS> hostname

*YOURPCNAME*
```

---

If this isn't what you want to do, let me know and we'll get you sorted.

Comment: You can either open an additional `PSSession` back to your host pc, or use `Invoke-Command -ComputerName` to send them back.  Another option would be to just send commands to the remote computer when you need to, or step in and out of the PSSession as I highlight above.  Those are the only options though.