# Cannot Move Computer to Target OU - PowerShell Script

Tags: powershell

I am getting the below error for this PowerShell script that connects to a remote DC and imports the AD module as well as gets the local computer name to move it to specified OU based on the name

```
$remServer="DC1"
$s=new-PSSession -Computer $remServer
Invoke-Command -Session $s -script {Import-Module ActiveDirectory}
Import-PSSession -Session $s -module ActiveDirectory 

$movePC = gc env:computername

if($movePC.substring(5,3) -imatch "Dbs"){
$TargetOU ='ou=DB Servers,ou=PRD,ou=Servers,dc=com,dc=company,dc=net'
Get-ADComputer $movePC | Move-ADObject  -Targetpath $TargetOU}

Remove-PSSession -Session $s


Script     1.0        tmp_54y3mzbf.25i                    {Add-
ADCentralAccessPolicyMember, Add-ADComputerServiceAccount, Add-
ADDomainControllerPasswordReplicationPolicy, Add-...
The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either 
because the command does not take pipeline input or the input and its 
properties do not match any of 
the parameters that take pipeline input.
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (CN=123123DBSTST0...company,DC=net:PSObject) [Move-ADObject], ParameterBindingException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : InputObjectNotBound,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.MoveADObject
+ PSComputerName        : DC1**
```

Comment: Try using Get-ADObject instead of Get-ADComputer.

Comment: Do you not have the ActiveDirectory module on your local PC?

Comment: @EBGreen if I do that, it says it cannot find the computer object "cannot find an object with identity: '123123DBSTST01' under ... It definitely exists though and just running GET-ADComputer works

Comment: @TheCorrigible1, a requirement is to import it from the DC as this will be ran as an SCCM script when imaging

Comment: @HenryB Does DC1 do the processing?

Comment: yes it does.....

Comment: yes please delete this thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a shot:

```
$Server = 'DC1'
$s = New-PSSession -Computer $Server
Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock {Import-Module -Name 'ActiveDirectory'}
Import-PSSession -Session $s -Module ActiveDirectory 

If ($env:ComputerName.Substring(5,3) -eq 'dbs')
{
    $TargetOU = 'ou=DB Servers,ou=PRD,ou=Servers,dc=com,dc=company,dc=net'
    $TargetPC = Get-ADComputer -Identity $env:ComputerName
    If ($TargetPC)
    {
        Move-ADObject -Identity $TargetPC -TargetPath $TargetOU -TargetServer $Server
    }
    Else
    {
        Write-Host "Failed to find $env:ComputerName on domain!"
    }
}

Remove-PSSession -Session $s
```

Comment: I get error: "Directory object not found"  ADIdentityNotFoundException but I know it exists because I can Write-Host $currentOU = Get-ADComputer $env:computername

Comment: Are all devices in the same domain @HenryB?

Comment: yes. The computer account is in (currently) ou=Non-Compliant,ou=PRD,ou=Servers,dc=com,dc=company,dc=net'

Comment: Get-ADComputer -Identity $env:ComputerName can also see it and points to the current OU

Comment: Move-ADObject -Identity $env:computername -TargetPath $TargetOU -TargetServer $Server also fails "cannot find object with identity '123123DBSTST01'

Comment: Get-ADComputer $TargetPC | Move-ADObject -Identity $TargetPC -TargetPath $TargetOU -TargetServer $Server produces an error "Cannot bind parameter 'Identity' cannot convert value to type Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADComputer"

Comment: If you go into your DC, can you manually find the PC object? @HenryB

Comment: yes of course...